# Passing Custom Data to Fancybox Instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fancybox, fancybox-3

I am trying to integrate Fancybox 3 into my app. In this, I am creating a custom button which process functions based on that instance and it requires additional data about that instance, for example `photoId` and `settingsId` for that instance. As an example:

**HTML:**

In this HTML, I want to pass an object data like `{photoId : 1, settingsId: 30}`, for each instance that will be used in the custom fancybox button method.

```
<a class="fbelements" href="http://example.com/img1.jpg" data-caption="Image 1">
<img src="http://example.com/thumb/img1.jpg" />
<!-- Want to pass: {photoId : 1, settingsId: 30} -->
</a>

<a class="fbelements" href="http://example.com/img2.jpg" data-caption="Image 2">
<img src="http://example.com/thumb/img2.jpg" />
<!-- Want to pass: {photoId : 2, settingsId: 41} -->
</a>
```

Jquery:

```
// Create template for custom button
$.fancybox.defaults.btnTpl.custombutton = '<button data-fancybox-custombutton class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--download" title="Download" >' +
              '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">' +
                '<path d="M18.62 17.09V19H5.38v-1.91zm-2.97-6.96L17 11.45l-5 4.87-5-4.87 1.36-1.32 2.68 2.64V5h1.92v7.77z"></path>' +
              '</svg>' +
'</button>';

// Make button clickable using event delegation
$('body').on('click', '[data-fancybox-custombutton]', function() {
                  // Here I need to access the object data for each of that respective instance
                  // For example: {photoId : 1, settingsId: 30}

 });

$().fancybox({
     selector : '.fbelements',
     closeExisting: true,
     fullScreen: true,
     thumbs: false,
     touch: true,
     infoBar: true,
     buttons: [
        "custombutton",
        "zoom",
        "slideShow",
        "fullScreen",
        "close"
     ],
   });
```

How is that possible? How can I pass additional data for each fancybox gallery instances so that data can be used in the custom button for that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `data-*` attributes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store custom data on your links.
2. This is how you get reference to original trigger element (e.g., link or button) for current item:

   ```
   $.fancybox.getInstance().current.opts.$orig
   ```
3. Then simply use `.data()` (https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) to retrieve your data from your trigger element.

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RXbeQL?editors=1010

Comment: Thats brilliant and it works. I passed the entire object like this: `data-item="{photoId : 1, settingsId: 30}"` and then retrieved it using `$.fancybox.getInstance().current.opts.$orig.data('item')`. Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted to access.